# Xamarin.Forms : When should I unhook the control's events in ContentPage

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In our xamarin.forms application we are creating 10 text boxes inside a ContentPage. Then we are hooking TextChanged events of these textboxes.

Sample Code

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PinView : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Some Code
    }
}
```

Now My question is should I care about unhooking these events? if 'Yes' then please let me know how and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would subscribe using XAML, then for sure you don't need to worry about it - events are unsubscribed automatically. If you subscribe using code, then it looks like it should be covered by the framework (the page gets disposed), [but it's advised to do it anyway](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/188). It may be a good idea to ask the xamarin forms team on github.

Comment: Link answered everything I wanted to know. Thanks @michal